# R regex extract standalone characters

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm trying to extract letter R or O that stands alone from multiple columns. By standalone, I mean R or O (i) separated by space or (ii) that is the only value in a cell. Here's a reproducible example. Suppose I want to extract standalone R or O from column `X1` and `X2`.

```
df <- data.frame(X1 = c( "EHO", "X 1 R","R"),
                 X2 = c( "Y R E", "X A 1", "AER"), 
                 X3 = NA)
```

Here's desired outcome.

```
data.frame(X1 = c("", "R", "R"),
           X2 = c("R", "", ""))
```

Here's what I've tried so far. The first approach is problematic because R from AER and O from EHO is extracted (also R from "Y R E" is not extracted).

```
require(stringr)
sapply(df[,1:2], function(x) ifelse( df$X3 %in% NA, str_extract(x, "\\s?[O|R]$"), X3))
```

So I've tried this, which solves above problem, but now it fails to extract R from `df[3,1]`.

```
sapply(df[,1:2], function(x) ifelse( df$X3 %in% NA, str_extract(x, "(?![A-Z]+?)\\s?[O|R]$?"), X3))
```

How should I fix the pattern to get this?

Comment: Questions tend to be easier to understand when the statement of the problem and examples (including the desired result for each), has been completed before the author's efforts to solve the problem are presented. Here I suggest you move "Here's the desired outcome"... to right before "Here's what I've tried so far...". As it is you are leading readers through your code before they know what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @CarySwoveland: Thanks for the suggestion. I updated the OP accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use word boundaries :

```
sapply(df, stringr::str_extract, '\\b[RO]\\b')

#     X1  X2  X3
#[1,] NA  "R" NA
#[2,] "R" NA  NA
#[3,] "R" NA  NA
```

However, note that `str_extract` will extract only one of  `"R"` or `"O"` whichever comes first.

```
stringr::str_extract('EH R O', '\\b[RO]\\b')
#[1] "R"
```

If you want to extract both of them you might need to use `str_extract_all`.

Comment: It seems like I don't need to use the vertical line ```|``` between R and O inside the bracket... Hmm.. then what can I do if I want to match not either R or O but RO? ["RO"] should work?

Comment: Don't use `[]` in that case. You can use `\\bRO\\b`.

Comment: Got it. Thanks as always!!